# MPAndroidChart BarChart show limit in Y-axis

Tags: android, limit, bar-chart, mpandroidchart

I am newbie in MPAndroidChart and this is what I want to do:

I want to add a set of (or single) values. I am having the following problem:

I wish that my showing max value be 100%, I do not want that max value be fixed to the current values.

Therefore, I am getting this:

[image]

And, I want something like this:

[image]

How can I do this?

**EDIT:**

I am adding my code.

```
private void show() {
    List<String> valsX = new ArrayList<String>();
    valsX.add("Column1");

    BarDataSet percentageDataSet = buildSimpleColumn(40, getResources().getColor(mHoloBlueColor), "Column1");

    BarData data = new BarData(valsX);
    data.addDataSet(percentageDataSet);
    barChart.setData(data);
    barChart.invalidate();
}

private BarDataSet buildSimpleColumn(int value, int color, String columnName) {
    List<BarEntry> valsY = new ArrayList<BarEntry>();
    valsY.add(new BarEntry(value, 0));

    List<Integer> colors = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    colors.add(color);

    BarDataSet dataSet = new BarDataSet(valsY, columnName);
    dataSet.setColors(colors);

    return dataSet;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I haven't tried it, but this should work:

```
YAxis yAxis = mChart.getAxisLeft();
yAxis.setAxisMaxValue(100f);
yAxis.setAxisMinValue(0f);
```

[More info](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/wiki/YAxis-(YLabels))

Comment: Thanks for your response, @Sander! Unfortunately it didn't work. I am adding my code, maybe there is something wrong